# Failed to push an app in heroku with python

Tags: python, django, git, heroku

im trying to deploying an app with python django..

But when i get this error:

From my build log in heroku..

```
-----> Python app detected
....
-----> Installing requirements with pip
...

       Collecting psycopg2==2.6.2

         Downloading psycopg2-2.6.2.tar.gz (376 kB)

           ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

            command: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-a0nakbaj/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-a0nakbaj/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-a0nakbaj/psycopg2/pip-egg-info

                cwd: /tmp/pip-install-a0nakbaj/psycopg2/

           Complete output (7 lines):
.....

           Error: could not determine PostgreSQL version from '12.2'

           ----------------------------------------

       ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.

 !     Push failed
```

Here is my requeriments.txt if you need it:

```
colorama==0.4.1
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==2.2.1
django-qr-code==1.0.0
gunicorn==19.9.0
Pillow==6.0.0
psycopg2==2.6.2
pytz==2019.1
qrcode==6.1
six==1.12.0
sqlparse==0.3.0
whitenoise==4.1.2
```

Anyone can help me with whis?

Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpsycopg2%5D+Error%3A+could+not+determine+PostgreSQL+version+from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku recommends upgrade psycopg2 to 2.7 and up.